# how to get values from jquery querystring in servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am using jquery.form.js to get some values from a file.I am getting the values in a querystring when i am trying to submit that values from the jsp page.but i am unable to get those values in the servlet.This is my querystring value

This is my HTML Page with Jquery

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {            
      $('#fileUploadForm').ajaxForm({                 
        beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
        success: SubmitSuccesful,
        error: AjaxError                               
      });                                    
    });            

    function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
      var queryString = $.param(formData);
      var url = document.URL;

      alert('BeforeSend method: \n\nAbout to submit: \n\n' +url+"?"+queryString);
      return true;
    }

    function AjaxError() {
      alert("An AJAX error occured.");
    }

    function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {        
      alert("SuccesMethod:\n\n" + responseText);
    }    
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="fileUploadForm" method="post" action="AServlet" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="filename" />
  <input type="file" id="postedFile" name="postedFile" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>



protected void doGET(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("------------------");
    String a = request.getParameter("filename");

    System.out.println(a);
}

}
```

Also the Web.xml here

```
<servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>AServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>AServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.servlet.AServlet</servlet-class>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>AServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/AServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Please don't write new code with jQuery 1.3. It is ancient and jQuery has changed a lot since then.

Answer (score 0):

1. ensure that your query url format like http://yourhostname:port/contextpath?param1=value2&param2=value2. Maybe you miss the ?.
2. Through URL request, it's a `GET` request, not the `POST` request. so in your servlet, you should get the parameter in the `doGet` method. Also you can invoke the `doPost` method in the `doGet` method. so your all request will be handled in `doPost` method.

Comment: I posted the screen shot i am getting .that is taken by the browser itself.If it is an issue of ? how i will put that??

Comment: You can use chrome console platform and then change to the network tab, watch your request details. In each request header, you can see that the form data you posted. if you don't see any form data in the request header. It must me some place you don't write correct. Can post your whole key javascript, html and servlet code here?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason, cause you have use the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to submit the form, which can not get the field value through `request.getParameter(key)`. Cause this is not the normal plain text submit.

If you want to get the field value, you can use the `SmartUpload` plugin or use the servlet upload component.

Below are the code:

```
    DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    Map<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    try {
        Map<String,List<FileItem>> items = upload.parseParameterMap(request);
        for (Entry<String, List<FileItem>> item: items.entrySet()) {
            for (FileItem fileItem : item.getValue()) {
                fields.put(item.getKey(), fileItem.getString());
            }
        }
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Entry<String, Object> field : fields.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(field.getKey() + ":" + field.getValue());
    }
```